# What is p pointing to in int x=259; char *p = (char*)&x;?

Tags: c, pointers

I came across a wield code and I can't understand it:

```
     int x=259;
     char *p = (char*)&x;
     printf("%d ", *p);
     printf("%d ", *(p + 1));
     printf("%d ", *(p + 2));
     printf("%d ", *(p + 3));
```

The output is:

```
     3 1 0 0
```

I've try changing x to many different numbers, the results made me more confused

```
     X            Output
    127           127 0 0 0
    128          -128 0 0 0
  256*127         0 127 0 0
  256*128         0 -128 0 0
```

so on...

Can someone explain what is p pointing to in

```
    char *p = (char*)&x;
```

and what does it print out.
Thank you.

Comment: Hint: 259 = 0x0103

Comment: `x` is an `int`. `&x` is the address of `x` and so it is a pointer to an `int`. `(char *)&x` type casts from a pointer to an `int` to a pointer to a `char`, since that's what `p` is. So `p` points to the first character (or byte) of `x`. If your processor is little endian (e.g., x86), that would be the low byte of the `int` value in `x`. Also keep in mind that `char` is a signed byte value. So it's range is -128 to 127. If you piece all that together, it explains what you're seeing. You have to think in terms of how the number is represented in the machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @lurker. It was the negetive value that confused me, I didnt notice the range of  char.

Comment: Your question title uses `{}` around the declarations. Your actual code doesn't. This makes a major difference. Why does your question title include these `{}`?

Comment: Technically, I'm afraid the code as posted might have undefined behavior unless you change the type of `p` to `unsigned char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int x=259;
 char *p = (char*)&x;
```

x is 4 bytes `0x03 0x01 0x00 0x00` since the machine you are on is little endian (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

so

- p points at the first byte = 3
- p+1 points at 1
- p+ 2 and + 3 points at 0

you can do the same analysis for other values.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your architecture.

It's pointing to the first byte of the int representation.

On a little endian machine it will be the low order byte of 259 , which is 3.

On a big endian machine it will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

X is an int (4 bytes) But p is a pointer to a char (1 byte). 
So p is pointing to the first byte of the int representation.

Thats why you are getting `3 1 0 0` because 256 is represented that way `0x03 0x01 0x00 0x00` on a little endian machine.

In the other cases you are getting the minus (e.g  -128) because the first bit of the byte is 1. And it thinks that it' a negative number.

(the binary representation of 128 on a little endian machine is : `10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`)

Comment: Mostly correct, except `char` is not necessarily signed and the last phrase is confusing because we are not discussing 128-bit representations... but rather *binary representations of the value `128`*

Comment: You are right I am changing it. thanks for your comment.